# Unexplained exception using the Google Places iOS SDK after upgrade to Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, google-places-api, swift3, xcode8, google-places

I cannot get even the demonstration code to work after converting it to swift 3.0. I have tried everything I can think of to no avail.

The exception is very unhelpful and the stack trace as well. (see the screenshot)

[image]

This is the swift 2.3 code, which works perfectly well:

```
@IBAction func getCurrentPlace(sender: UIButton) {

    placesClient?.currentPlaceWithCallback({
    (placeLikelihoodList: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        self.nameLabel.text = "No current place"
        self.addressLabel.text = ""

        if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
            let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
            if let place = place {
                self.nameLabel.text = place.name
                self.addressLabel.text = place.formattedAddress!.componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
                    .joinWithSeparator("\n")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And this is the equivalent in swift 3.0:

```
@IBAction func go(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
    placesClient?.currentPlace(callback: {
        (placeLikelihoodList: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error: NSError?) in

        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Couldn't find a location", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }

        if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
            let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
            if let place = place {
                self.testlabel.text = place.name
            }
        }


        } as! GMSPlaceLikelihoodListCallback)
}
```

The exception stops me here: `as! GMSPlaceLikelihoodListCallback`

Anyone have a clue as to what's going on?

Comment: I haven't worked with these but, why is the casting(`as! GMSPlaceLikelihoodListCallback`) necessary?

Comment: I thought the same thing. It won't compile without it though and there's a friendly "fix-it" tip from xcode that forcefully adds it.

Comment: You probably need `Error` instead of `NSError` in the callback parameters

Comment: @dan That was totally the problem! I cannot believe I didn't catch that!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
    placesClient?.currentPlace(callback: { (place, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Couldn't find a location", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }

        if let placeLikelihoodList = place {
            let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
            if let place = place {
                self.lblOrigem.text = place.formattedAddress
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)